# Cloud Run: Firestore create is not working

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-run

My application (Spring-Boot) is running under `Google Cloud Run`. It's API is called by `Google Pub-Sub`. Application is writing data to `Google Firestore`.
While it triggering from the pub-sub, Sometimes I cannot see the data are not store in the  `Google Firestore`. And its showing following error:

```
Container Sandbox: Unsupported syscall setsockopt(0x2c,0x29,0x31,0x3e0ce8bef5cc,0x4,0x3e0cdc036100). It is very likely that you can safely ignore this message and that this is not the cause of any error you might be troubleshooting. Please, refer to https://gvisor.dev/c/linux/amd64/setsockopt for more information.
```

But If call the API directly. Then I can see the data is storing in the `Google Firestore`. And after that Pub-Sub calls also working fine. But this is not consistence for Pub-Sub calls.

Comment: Do you use the latest version of the libraries?

Comment: This is a known notice that is emitted, your application error could be elsewhere. https://github.com/google/gvisor/issues/1739

Comment: Usually that warning is just a warning and not an error. If there is something wrong with the API call, you Java program would be throwing an exception.